# Adding a cumulative sum to a table in MATLAB using a loop

Tags: matlab, cumulative-sum

I am new to MATLAB. For a uni project, I am interested in adding a column to an existing table using a loop. For illustration purposes, I am using the following image in order to explain my situation.

[image]

As can be seen in the image, in the current table there are some values in column A (value for a subcategory) and some values in column B (target values for a category). I need to create a column with cumulative sum against the subcategory values for each category of column B as shown in the desired table.

I was trying to use `cumsum()` function in the following manner but does not seem to work.

```
for i = table.B(1):table.B(end)
    table.C(i)=cumsum(table.A(i))
end
```

I understand that there could be some indexing problem, but don't know how to address this issue.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Next time be sure to include a minimal example with code, not an image

Comment: `cumsum` doesn't work because you're not looking to add a cumulative sum. You want to add the sum over all values with the same category.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done easily with [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) to produce a vector of grouping indices, and [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) to compute the sum of each group:

```
T = table([12; 15;18; 11; 20; 22; 26; 32; 35; 40; 25; 35], ...
          [60; 60; 60; 60; 75; 75; 75; 200; 200; 200; 200; 200], ...
          'VariableNames', {'A', 'B'}); % example data with columns 'A', 'B'
[~, ~, ind] = unique(T.B, 'stable'); % grouping indices
sums = accumarray(ind, T.A); % sum of each group
T.C = sums(ind); % build result column
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Luis. I hope it can be used in my project.

Comment: Is it possible to incorporate conditions in the sum process? Because there are two types of situations and I want the sums to be calculated in two separate columns according to those two conditions. I was trying to do the following but does not seem to work...

if condition_1
 sums_c1 = accumarray(ind, T.A);
elseif condition_2
 sums_c2 = accumarray(ind, T.A);
end

Is there any way around it?
Thanks in advance.
Shahzada

Comment: @ShahzadaImran I don't understand what you mean, sorry. Maybe post a new question with a clear example